# Flutter - Cache_network_image. I replaced old image with new image with same name. But it doesn't affect on app

Tags: flutter, caching, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter. I have used library of "cache_network_image" which help to show images from the internet and keep them in the cache directory. In first load, it download the images and stored in cache directory(cache manager) and displayed in app.

Example. I have an image(test.png), it downloaded from network and stored in cache successfully. But If I replace test.png image with new image with same name of test.png. So It should display new image
with that same name(test.png). It's displaying only old image.

The cache_network_image library not working properly. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: whats the goal? it might be that you have definitely replaced wrong file

Comment: My goal is cache_network_image should display all new images which I uploaded. It only shows "old image" which downloaded from network and now showing newly uploaded images.

Comment: Actually is working as expected. The library is using the URL to cache the image, so in your case you have two different images with the same URL. The library will display the first image you've downloaded and cached. If you uninstall the app and run again, the second image will be shown.

Comment: Thanks..Is there is any option to avoid or overcome this issue. Because everytime I couldn't uninstall app and run again

Comment: if you are replacing the file at the url, then its impossible to the cache manager as it relies on the url of the file to identify it locally. it will download it again only if the local file is missing or the url changes.

Comment: Okay.. Then, if I upload new image in the directory, cache_network_image will automatically download and will show in app. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

no, it doesn't care whats in the end of the url, all it cares is whether file exists locally, if it doesn't then only it'll fetch from the url, if you want to refetch the updated image you have clear the cache, delete the app data or if you want to clear programmatically

```
var cm = DefaultCacheManager();
cm.emptyCache();
```